# Nutch on EMR problem reading from S3

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, nutch

Hi I am trying to run [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) 1.2 on Amazon's EMR.
To do this I specifiy an input directory from S3.  I get the following error:

```
Fetcher: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    This file system object (hdfs://ip-11-202-55-144.ec2.internal:9000)
    does not support access to the request path 
    's3n://crawlResults2/segments/20110823155002/crawl_fetch'
    You possibly called FileSystem.get(conf) when you should have called
    FileSystem.get(uri, conf) to obtain a file system supporting your path.
```

I understand the difference between `FileSystem.get(uri, conf)`, and `FileSystem.get(conf)`.  If I were writing this myself I would `FileSystem.get(uri, conf)` however I am trying to use existing Nutch code.

I asked this question, and someone told me that I needed to modify `hadoop-site.xml` to include the following properties: `fs.default.name`, `fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId`, `fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey`.  I updated these properties in `core-site.xml` (`hadoop-site.xml` does not exist), but that didn't make a difference.  Does anyone have any other ideas? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Never used Nutch, but maybe check if the resource you are trying to get is publicly available (won't harm to do that just for testing), also try replacing (again just for testing) s3n:// -> s3://. I guess it should work with s3n and with creds specified but more tests won't harm

Answer (score 0):

try to specify in

> hadoop-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem</value>
</property>
```

This will mention to Nutch that by default S3 should be used

Properties

> fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId 
>   and 
>   fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey

specification you need only in case when your S3 objects are placed under authentication (In S3 object can be accessed to all users, or only by authentication)